# Postgresql cannot drop trigger

Tags: postgresql, trigger

I'm running the following with alembic:

```
def downgrade():
    conn = op.get_bind()
    conn.execute(sa.sql.text('''
DROP TRIGGER update_rated_trigger ON rating;
DROP FUNCTION update_rated;
    '''))
```

It gives the error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) syntax error at or near ";"
>   LINE 2: DROP TRIGGER "update_rated_trigger";

Not sure what the problem is with postgres?

Comment: @Phil running just one statement without `;` still gives `syntax error at end of input`

Comment: I'm not sure why you need the `sa.sql.text()` magic, does it replace the normal cursor?  Or is `conn` already a cursor?  And Phil said to remove the second `DROP` statement, not any quotes.

Comment: I'm sure I've run multiple statements in one `execute()` with SQLAlchemy. That's (probably) not the reason. In the code you have `DROP TRIGGER update_rated_trigger ON rating;` but the error has: `DROP TRIGGER "update_rated_trigger";` Where did the `ON rating` go?

Comment: This is not a Postgres problem. It is a problem with that alembic thing.

Comment: Can you post the output of ´print sa.sql.text('''
DROP TRIGGER update_rated_trigger ON rating;
DROP FUNCTION update_rated;
    ''')´ to see if that outputs valid SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that Postgres requires you to include the braces at the end of the function name when calling `DROP FUNCTION`.

If you change your code to the following, it'll work:

```
def downgrade():
    conn = op.get_bind()
    conn.execute(sa.sql.text('''
DROP TRIGGER update_rated_trigger ON rating;
DROP FUNCTION update_rated();
    '''))
```